# How to use split function for file in python?

Tags: python, file, split

I have a file with a bunch of information. For example, all of the lines follow the same pattern as this:

```
     <school>Nebraska</school>
```

I am trying to use the split function to only retrieve 'Nebraska'. This is what I have so far, but I'm not sure what to put to make it cut off both parts instead of just the first.

```
   with open('Pro.txt') as fo:
       for rec in fo:
          print(rec.split('>')[1])
```

With this I get:

```
    Nebraska</school
```

Comment: If it's XML or HTML, and it looks as though it is, you should use a proper parser such as BeautifulSoup (HTML) or LXML (XML). Python also comes with parsers that will do the trick, though the ones I suggested are better.

Comment: Use an XML parser, either [built-in](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.html) or a PyPI module like `lxml` or `BeautifulSoup`. Don't try to roll your own XML parsing code.

Comment: Do you have an example of the file? It's possible that you're dealing with a subset of *ML that may be easier to work with.

Answer (score 1):

You've cut off part of the string. Keep going in the same fashion:

```
>>> s = '<school>Nebraska</school>'
>>> s.split('>')[1]
'Nebraska</school'
>>> s.split('>')[1].split('<')[0]
'Nebraska'
```

That said, you should parse HTML with an HTML parser like BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = '<school>Nebraska</school>'
```

in:

```
s.split('>')
```

out:

```
['<school', 'Nebraska</school', '']
```

in:

```
s.split('>')[1].split('<')
```

out:

```
['Nebraska', '/school']
```

in:

```
s.split('>')[1].split('<')[0]
```

out:

```
'Nebraska'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression:

```
import re
regexp = re.compile('<school>(.*?)<\/school>')

with open('Pro.txt') as fo:
    for rec in fo:
        match = regexp.match(rec)
        if match: 
            text = match.groups()[0]
            print(text)
```