# How to split each line from file to it's own string in Python?

Tags: python, file

I have a file with a bunch of information with this following format:

```
    <name>New York Jets</name>
```

I am trying to get each line of the file into it's own string. For example, I want this line to say "This is the roster for the New York Jets." I have this so far, but it has "This is the roster for the" for every single line. I think I have to use-

```
    inputString.split('\n')
```

But I'm not sure where to put it in at. This is what I have so far.

```
    def summarizeData(filename):
        with open(filename,"r") as fo:
             for rec in fo:
                 name=rec.split('>')[1].split('<')[0]
                 print("Here is the roster for the %s." % (name))
```

and I call summarizeData("NewYorkJets.txt"). So basically I am trying to split each line from the file to get it in it's own string

Comment: it is possible that the file is an XML file, and you'd be **much** better off using an XML parser.

Comment: Works fine for me. You do not have the data you think you have. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: And it's a bit odd that you'd use [my answer to your earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41008126/how-to-use-split-function-for-file-in-python/41008171#41008171), but neither upvote it nor accept it.

Comment: Additionally, there's no need to create multiple accounts. It just makes it harder to determine what sort of help you've already gotten and how you're progressing on your task.

Answer (score 0):

```
from xml.dom import minidom
```

xmldoc = minidom.parse('filename.txt')

itemlist = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('item')

for s in itemlist:
    print(s.attributes['name'].value)

you can read a file having tags like this, and retrieve the values.