# Why is this split method not working correctly?

Tags: python, string, split

I'm trying to split

```
<team>
```

into just team, here is the code I'm using:

```
s = "<team>"
s.split(">")[1]
s
'<team>'
s.split(">")[1].split("<")[0]
s
'<team>
```

As you can see, it's still leaving me with

```
<team>
```

anyone know why>

Comment: `split()` doesn't change the original string `s`, it returns the split strings array.

Comment: Use trim () function of str to remove (<,>)

Comment: Did you [make](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41008126/how-to-use-split-function-for-file-in-python) yet another [account](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41030021/how-to-split-each-line-from-file-to-its-own-string-in-python), or are you classmates? Either way, please attempt to make your own progress on this task.

Comment: @Jeenitkhatri - This is Python.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 - For python you can use :  "<team>".strip('<>') it gives you o/p: team

Answer (score 0):

`str.split()` function returns a list, it does not split the string in place.

You'll need to make a new variable:

```
s = "<team>"
t = s.split(">")[1]
t
```